# Dataflow Job success but data is not transferred

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-composer

I have Cloud Dataflow Job to pull the data from Oracle to Google CloudSQL in GCP Project which has VPC/VPN setup. Scheduled this dataflow job using Composer and executed it periodically. It was working fine, however sometime Dataflow Job executes successfully but data is not moved to CloudSQL. Nothing error/ specific events from Logs. Its weird...This happens very rare... It would be good if any one give suggestion to find out the root cause of this case.

Here is the dataflow operator definition,

```
dataFlowStatus = DataFlowJavaOperator( task_id='dataflowlabelstatus', jar=jar_pathr, gcp_conn_id='google_cloud_default', options={ 'project': project_id, 'region': gcp_region, 'usePublicIps': ip_condition, 'stagingLocation': staging_location, 'tempLocation': staging_location, 'subnetwork': gcp_sub_network, 'RTMaxDate': "{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='validateDate', key='job_last_fetch_date') }}", 'oracleJDBCSource': oracle_connection_url, 'oracleUserName': rm_username, 'oraclePassword': rm_password, 'postgreUserName_RT': receipt_username, 'postgrePassword_RT': receipt_password, 'postgresDatabaseName_RT': receipt_schema, 'postgreUserName_Label': label_username, 'postgrePassword_Label': label_password, 'postgresDatabaseName_Label': label_schema, 'cloudSqlInstance_RT': receipt_cloud_instance, 'cloudSqlInstance_Label': label_cloud_instance, 'autoscalingAlgorithm': 'BASIC', 'maxNumWorkers': '50' }, dag=dag )
```

Comment: It sounds you could ask it in user@airflow.apache.org or dev@airflow.apache.org.

Comment: Does your pipeline work without using google-cloud-composer?

Comment: Hi @RuiWang, Thanks for your help. Let me send my concern email to airflow team. Also, for your question, dataflow pipeline works fine in direct execution like maven command as well as google-cloud-composer scheduling. However some occasions dataflow pipeline did not transfer the data even dataflow Job is Succeeded. Analysed both composer and dataflow logs but unable to find any clue..

Comment: Also, is there any possibilities that composer will be hang for while even pipeline is success, do you have any idea. If yes, then may be it would be the reason for not transferring the data.

Comment: If the Airflow workflow hangs even when the pipeline is successful, then there might be a bug in the operators you are using. If an operator is in charge of moving the data to Cloud SQL, then it could be a failure in the workflow, otherwise it is probably a failure within the Dataflow job.

Comment: As long as you can run the pipeline alone (e.g. not using airflow/composer) without a problem, there shouldn't be a problem about dataflow/beam.